# How to commit codes from multiple projects of IntelliJ to one Microsoft TFS project GIT account

Tags: android, spring, git, tfs, intellij-idea

I have 3 projects (2 using spring mvc+REST & 1 for android application) using IntelliJ. I do have microsoft TFS account out of which I can commit codes from one of my Spring MVC Project. I want to commit the other two to the same TFS Git project account. How to go about it.
When checked in JetBrains i did find integrating only one project to TFS GIT. Is my requirement reasonable or can't be done at all? Pls advise.

Example

My two SPring MVC Projects (in IntelliJ)
1. Communication
2. Billing

My android project (in IntelliJ)
3. WifiDirect

Microsoft TFS GIT Project account
Commn

I want to integrate Communication + Billing + WifiDirect to TFS project account Commn.

So that I can have a central repository + project tracking for my entire project work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow theses steps : (Follow theses keywords also)

1. Create you Team Project Collection, just (Set of Team project, one project pemit you to isolate one project & follow differents metrics ).
2. Create your Team Project, just one.
3. Install Team Explorer (Add In Visual Studio permit you to access TFS API from VS)
4. Access to Source Control (Enter url server & credentials)
5. Open your solution or project on  Visual Studio
6. Select Add to source Control (TFS2012 permit you to have Local Workspace or Server Workspace).
7. Click on Source Control  in order to visualize your code